# NodeJS Async in Lambda does not run all entries

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, asynchronous, aws-lambda

I have a NodeJs10 Lambda function to parse entries from my database and save them back to the database. When I run this locally, it parses all entries. When I run it in a Lambda function, it only parses 3-4 entries. My best guess is that Lambda handles async calls differently, and thinks that all entries have been parsed.

How do I make my Lambda function run all the entries before shutting down?

My code looks like this globally:

```
'use strict';

// Packages
var Mercury = require('@postlight/mercury-parser');
var Mysql = require('mysql');

// All necessery sql Queries
var sqlSelect = "Select some stuff";
var sqlUpdateText = "Update some stuff";

exports.handler = async function(event, context) {
    // Define the database used in pools
    var pool = Mysql.createPool({
    });

    // Promise where the links and id's are fetched from the database
    let fetchLink = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        pool.getConnection((err, connection) => {   // Connection with the database
        });
    });

    // After getting the links and id's, parse the text from the links and put them in a JSON object
    return fetchLink.then(async function (dbresult) {
        if (dbresult.length > 0) {
            await parser();
        }
        return textObj;
    })
    // After parsing
        .then(function (textObj) {
            if (Object.getOwnPropertyNames(textObj).length !== 0) {
                pool.getConnection((err, connection) => {
                    if (err) throw err;
                    for (let id in textObj) {
                        // Do some db stuff
                    }
                    connection.release();
                    pool.end();
                });
            } else {
                pool.end();
            }
        })
        // Catch the error message's
        .catch(function (err) {
            console.log(err);
            pool.end();
        });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

handler function doesn't need to be async while you are not using await anywhere. if you return promise, it's async anyway. i'm not sure how `fetchLink` promise exacly looks, but here it resolve/reject nothing so function probably finishes on timeout. meaby you need fix it like this

```
    let fetchLink = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        pool.getConnection((err, connection) => {   // Connection with the database
            if(err) reject(err);
            resolve(connection);
        });
    });
```

also if you want to be sure that handler function finishes with releasing connection and ending pool, better return promises also after parsing and catching errors too.

```
    .then(function (textObj) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            if (Object.getOwnPropertyNames(textObj).length !== 0) {
                pool.getConnection((err, connection) => {
                    if (err) return reject(err);
                    for (let id in textObj) {
                        // Do some db stuff
                    }
                    connection.release();
                    pool.end();
                    resolve();
                });
            } else {
                pool.end();
                resolve();
            }
        }    
    })
```

if `connection.release()` and `pool.end()` functions are promises or have callbacks, also should be bound in Promise and awaited then.

Answer (score 0):

Lambda will not wait for your `fetchLink.then()` to be finished. In your case, adding `await` before `fetchLink.then()` will do the job.

```
// After getting the links and id's, parse the text from the links and put them in a JSON object
    return await fetchLink.then(async function (dbresult) {
        if (dbresult.length > 0) {
            await parser();
        }
        return textObj;
    })
```

If above solution still not solve your problem. Check if callbacks invoked async api had been handled correctly.

```
// After parsing
        .then(function (textObj) {
            if (Object.getOwnPropertyNames(textObj).length !== 0) {
                // HANDLE THIS ASYNC OR IT WILL NOT BE WAITED BY LAMBDA
                pool.getConnection((err, connection) => {
                    if (err) throw err;
                    for (let id in textObj) {
                        // Do some db stuff
                    }
                    connection.release();
                    pool.end();
                });
            } else {
                pool.end();
            }
        })
```

Docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-model-handler.html